# Java Arrays - How to create an array using a static method

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I am searching for the lines of code to create a new array using a method called insertRow(int[] row). With this method, users can insert 5 numbers to form an array. Then this array should be named row2. Please help.

```
public class App 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int[] row = new int[5];
        int[] row1 = {2,7,1,9,4};
        //int[] row2 = insertRow(row); this is wrong
    }

    public static void insertRow(int[] row)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < row.length; i++)
        {
            int number;
            do
                number = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insert the " + (i+1) + "th positif number"));
            while (getal < 0);

            row[i] = number;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You were on the right track: change the signature of your method to return `int[]`, allocate the `row` inside, and put your code in place of `...` below:

```
public static int[] insertRow() {
    int[] row = new int[5];
    ...
    return row;
}
```

Now this will work:

```
int[] row2 = insertRow(); // this is no longer wrong :)
```

Comment: I think that he named the method "insertRow" because he wants to keep what's already in the array. Your method replaces the old array with a new one.